# How to install cURL into visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, curl

I've been trying to get curl into vsc, so far I've managed to install curl and use commands in command prompt, but I have no idea how to implement it into VSC?

The path if needed is C:\curl-7.84.0-win64-mingw

(On another note, I'm trying to use it for C++ development)

Comment: Please explain, you need curl or libcurl?

Comment: Which compiler are you using with VSCode? From the path I assume it's MinGW but it would be good to confirm.

Comment: VSCode uses whatever terminal environment is installed on the system, perhaps you just want to install curl for windows?

Comment: If you're talking about `libcurl` for C and C++, here are my generic personal installation notes (for Linux) if this helps you get started at all: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/cpp#c-curl-library-installation--setup

Comment: There is no need to install libcurl into vs code, what you do need to do is configure your compiler commands to use it. How are you building your code?

Comment: Well these are my properties files:

Comment: {
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}

Comment: Do you by any chance have discord perhaps? The character limit on here is making it very difficult.